send custom variable to Botpress API
When initiating a conversation with Botpress via NodeJS using the whatsapp-web.js library,
I'd like to initially send the phone number of the person starting the conversation.
I'm trying to achieve this in the following way:
client.on('message', message => {

    console.log('number', message.from);
    if( message.from == '559295105867@c.us' ){
        const number = message.from.split('@')
        const from = number[0]
        axios({
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            data: {
                type: "text",
                text: message.body,
                payload: {from}
            },
            url: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/v1/bots/bot-zdg/converse/552298120000"
        }).then(async res => {
            const {responses} = res.data

            for (let index = 0; index < responses.length; index++) {
                const {text, choices} = responses[index]
                let choice = ''
                if( choices ){

                    const rows = choices.map(c => `> *${c.value}*: ${c.title}`)
                    choice = rows.join('\n')
                }
                const msg = `${text}\n${choice}`
                client.sendMessage(message.from, msg)
                await delay(message.from)   
            }
        }).catch(e =>{
            console.log('error',e.response.data);
            console.log('error',e.message);
        })
    }

});

However, I'm getting the following error:
error {
  statusCode: 400,
  type: 'StandardError',
  message: 'Invalid payload: "payload" is not allowed',
  details: '',
  docs: 'https://botpress.com/docs',
  showStackInDev: true,
  stack: 'Error: Invalid payload: "payload" is not allowed\n' +
    '    at /snapshot/v12/packages/bp/dist/core/converse/converse-router.js',
  full: 'Invalid payload: "payload" is not allowed'
}
error Request failed with status code 400

As far as I know, the standard Botpress payload is:
{
  type: "text",
  text: "mensagem"
}

Is there a way for me to send an additional variable so that Botpress can read it?

I don't know if you have solved it yet, but I just found that you can send an attribute called "metadata". In your example, you would just rename "payload" to "metadata". Something like this:
axios.post(`https://botpress-server/api/v1/bots/botId/converse/${phonenumber}`,
            {"type": "text", "text": mensagem, "metadata": {"customId":"123456"}},
            {headers: botpress_headers}
        )

Hope it helps!

I'll try... thanks
